# Devise "<#User not initialized>" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have integrated devise in a pre-existing "User" Model. Here it is how it looks like

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

include AstroModels::Users::Validation
```

when i browse any authentication page. i get following error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
```

I have debug it using <%resource.inspect%> , i get following error,

```
<#User not initialized>
```

on the following line

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Also, i tried a stack overflow answer by changing

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

to

```
**<%= form_for(resource_name, :as => resource, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>**
```

But doesn't seem work. Just for info i'm integrating devise in an application that uses rails4.

For just more iinfor i have following in my application helper file.

```
  def resource_name
    :user    
  end

  def resource

  @resource ||= User.new
  end

 def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
 end
```

Any suggestion/workaround would be great help thanks.

Comment: The issue seems to be in your application. Why the user given to devise is not initialized? Is there an extension messing it up? I would investigate which gem is not playing well with Devise and them figure out if it is a Devise issue or the third party gem one.

Comment: Hi jose, there is a session_controller already in the app. but i think it shouldn't effect the devise behavior?

Comment: It shouldn't because devise/sessions#method is different than sessions#method in routes.rb.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i was inheriting my custom User Model with ActiveRecord::Base class and by ActiveRecord::Base when we inherit any class with it we can not have our own initialize method in that custom model. So i commented out initialize method in my custom model and the error was gone.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: It happened same to me, I'm able to fix it with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention routes.rb or the views you need to create a session, which initializes user.  Have you completed those tasks?  You should start with the Devise installation generator to add in the code including initializers:

```
rails generate devise:install
```

routes.rb has to include devise_for that is set for your application.  An example, not necessarily complete for you:

```
Sampleapp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
  resources :users
end
```

You can access the views in the Devise gem, or you can copy them to your own application so they can be customized like this:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

This will provide app/views/devise views as well as app/views/layouts needed to login and create a session, among others.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. i have already performed these steps but nothing worked.

Comment: Are you visiting new_user_session_path to login, create the session and initialize user?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you have done, showing the pertinent files?

Comment: Hi,

In my case i was inheriting my custom User Model with ActiveRecord::Base class and by ActiveRecord::Base when we inherit any class with it we can not have our own initialize method in that custom model. So i commented out initialize method in my custom model and the error was gone. 

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Please provide feedback.  Was the problem solved?  If so, how?  If not, how can we help?  Thanks...

Comment: Unfortunately, problem was not resolved. i have already investigated issue and commented last time. Thanks for your help.:)